# check if element has css position property setted up

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to be sure if parent element has css position property setted up ?

```
if(!$('#element').parent().css('position')){
    //here I need to be sure to avoid no rewrite the old position if position is already setted up
    //absolute fixed etc....
    $('#element').parent().css('position','relative')
}
```

Some like this work on cross browsers ?

Comment: That won't work as all elements will have a position set by default. To make your logic work you need to check if the value matches something you want eg `=== 'block'` or `=== 'static'`

Comment: You suggest better to check all this? `static absolute fixed sticky initial inherit or empty` ?

Comment: No. This gets the computed style. Computed style is not null by default and depends on all external and internal and default settings of browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below method :

```
function elementOrParentIsFixed(element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var $checkElements = $element.add($element.parents());
    var isFixed = false;
    $checkElements.each(function(){
        if ($(this).css("position") === "relative") {
            isFixed = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return 
}
```

Comment: [If you're going to rip off someone's code at least credit them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19474949/519413). Better still, vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Did a research and found this could help here !! :) ... learning as I go

Comment: You even failed at copying and pasting the entire function

Comment: @Danish In my searches I have not had the same luck :) ... so I'm left with the idea but I'm going to rewrite it for my case. Then I will check at least these: `static absolute fixed sticky`

Answer (score 0):

So based on @Danish suggestion (copy-pasted from : [Detect whether an element has position:fixed (possibly by parent element) via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474320/detect-whether-an-element-has-positionfixed-possibly-by-parent-element-via-jq/19474949#19474949) )

I write this:

```
function parentHasPosition(element){
    var parent = element.parent();
    if(
        parent.css('position') === 'static' ||
        parent.css('position') === 'absolute' ||
        parent.css('position') === 'fixed' ||
        parent.css('position') === 'sticky'
    ){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```